# Kendo binding attribute with string and variable

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

Is it possible to do something like:

```
<span data-bind="attr: { id: 'nav-' + id }"></span>
```

I use the 'id' in a few places in the html, so I need to prefix them, but this throws an 'unexpected string' error. Is there any way to do something like this or do I have to apply the prefix in the view model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't concatenate strings within a data-bind definition.
You need to apply it in the view model, e.g. by using a function in the view model:

```
var prefix = "nav-";

var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    id: "postfix",
    getId: function() {
        return prefix + this.get("id");
    }
});
```

Then use it like this:

```
<span data-bind="attr: { id: getId }"> using method in the view model </span>
```

Or you register custom bindings like this:

```
var prefix = "nav-";
kendo.data.binders.customId = kendo.data.Binder.extend({
    refresh: function () {
        var value = this.bindings["customId"].get();
        value = prefix + value;

        $(this.element).attr("id", value);

    }
});
```

Then use it like this:

```
<span data-bind="customId: id">using custom binding</span>
```

Working examples: http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/CEaXr/